# Open Eclipse Wizard or Eclipse MessageDialog in New Thread

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

I want to open an Eclipse `Wizard` or `MessageDialog` in a new thread, but somehow I always get an exception like this one:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-7" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4491)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4406)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4377)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Shell.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Shell.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.createShell(Window.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1096)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog.open(MessageDialog.java:330)
    at de.uka.ipd.sdq.beagle.gui.GuiController$DialogPolling.run(GuiController.java:126)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

when using code like this:

```
/**
 * Opens up the dialog displaying the actions "pause", "continue", and "abort" to the
 * user. These actions are regarding the analysis.
 */
private void engageDialog() {
    final String dialogTitle = "Beagle Analysis is Running";
    final String dialogMessage = "Beagle Analysis is running.";
    final String[] buttonLabels = {"Abort", "Pause"};
    this.messageDialog =
        new MessageDialog(this.shell, dialogTitle, null, dialogMessage, MessageDialog.INFORMATION, buttonLabels, 0);
    new Thread(new DialogPolling()).start();
}

private class DialogPolling implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final int buttonClick = GuiController.this.messageDialog.open(); // line 126

        if (buttonClick == 0) {
            System.out.println("User clicked 'Abort'.");
        }

        if (buttonClick == 1) {
            System.out.println("User clicked 'Pause'.");
        }
    }
}
```

This is from `GuiController` and line 126 is marked. Scroll to the right if you can't see the line number.

How can I open a Wizard or a MessageDialog in a new thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All wizards, dialogs, ... must be opened in the single SWT UI thread. You can use the `Display.syncExec` call in another thread to run the dialog open in the UI thread.

```
Display.getDefault().syncExec(runnable);
```

Your `Runnable` can call the dialog `open` and save the `buttonClick` value somewhere that you can access when `syncExec` returns.

Answer (score 0):

GUI systems are usually design as single thread because its almost impossible to write multi thread GUI system. There is to many user interactions and too many events.

Thats why GUI framework usually create his own dedicated thread and all GUI activity is going in this thread. For example Swing has its AWT thread. If long running operation is executing in this thread, it causes freeze of the program (program doesn't react to user input). If you want to avoid this, you must run your logic in different thread. But only your logic, not the GUI actions!

There are some useful classes to solve this issues - like **SwingWorked**, that is design to run *lengthy GUI-interaction tasks in a background thread*.

.